# How Show Text in windows taskbar Flutter Windows

Tags: flutter, dart, taskbar, flutter-windows

How to show text in windows taskbar

How to show text in windows taskbar Realtime like internet speed meter in flutter windows. I want to use it for my monitor application. So I need to show Realtime int in windows taskbar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsgg8.png)

Comment: You should provide more details about your question. You should add some code or some images to let people understand what you are looking for